# How to remove security notifications about unapproved software after upgrading to macos High Sierra?

Tags: security, high-sierra

Upgrading to High Sierra is really painful. I cannot do brew upgrade, I am getting thousands of security notifications - see the attached file.  There are some recipes in Internet but they are not working, maybe the latest upgrade does not allow them.  I can approve files one by one but there are hundreds of them.  Maybe at least I can approve all files in a directory? Or run a script approving all files?

Comment: I don't recognize this prompt. Are you running anti-virus software?

Comment: I am running brew upgrade, I uploaded the whole picture

Comment: That dialog says 'Bit9 Security Platform' so you should check with that company.  They are now named 'Carbon Black' and they do endpoint security.  It's not High Sierra that's causing you the problems, it's that software.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears you have an anti-virus application called Bit9. If it is causing more difficulty than help, you can always deactivate or uninstall it. If this is a institutionally managed machine, contact your system admin or help desk.

If you feel you need to have an anti-virus application, be sure to confirm that it will run correctly with macOS High Sierra. You may need to disable the anti-virus' blocking of scripts if you are intentionally running scripts for what you are doing.

Comment: Yes, our admin confirmed that Bit9 is installed.  Still, not clear why the problems started after installing High Sierra, I did not have them before

Answer (score -1):

This does not look like any Apple software dialog box. The icon is unfamiliar, .exe is not an application extension on OS X and there's no reason why Apple should want (nor you should be required to provide) any justification for running a piece of software, nor your email address when you approve it.

It looks like that might be Eclipse (or some other IDE) running behind your dialog? If so is it possible this is coming from a plugin for that application?